# Keep URL the same after changing page title

Tags: path-aliases

I create alias for every pages on my site. For example, if a page is called "My Page", then the alias will be "/my-page".

Is there a way to keep that URL the same even if I rename the page "My Page 1" ?

For the moment, it automatically changes the alias to "/my-page-1"

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default at */admin/config/search/path/settings*. Under 'Update Action' choose 'Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.'